# How to check the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Credential

Tags: c#, winforms, system.net.mail

I want to check that if i have input the right SenderEmail and MailPassword.What should I do?The code :

```
        //邮箱地址//EmailAddress
        string server = comboBox.Text;
        string SenderMail = EmailName.Text.ToString().Trim()+server;
        MessageBox.Show("邮箱地址为：" + SenderMail);
        //邮箱密码//EmailPassword
        string MailPassword = EmailPassword.Text.ToString().Trim();
        //发送服务器//SenderServer
        server = server.Substring(1);
        string SendServer = "smtp."+server;
        MessageBox.Show(SendServer);
        //新建SMTP客户端实例//Create a SmtpClient 
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SendServer, 25);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderMail, MailPassword);
        if (?????) { MessageBox.Show("Success!"); }
```

Comment: Authentication/relay errors are thrown when you attempt to .send the message, catch the corresponding exceptions

Comment: Yes, you can check as Alex mentioned, as well as you can use Regex to verify whether Email is correct.

Comment: Thanks,I‘ll try it tomorrow.@AlexK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the SenderEmail is correct you can use [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
        try
        {
            new MailAddress(SenderEmail);                
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            //The email address is not correct
        }
```